# SQL Server Adjusting calculation when Bool is changed

Tags: sql-server, bit

In Sql Server I am trying to add a column to calculate employees Extra Leave based on their start date, where apprentices do not get any. But I am getting an error. `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'`.

Also would there be a way that the extra leave starts calculating after their `Apprentice` is set to False.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
ADD AwardedLeave as CAST 
(


CASE
When [Apprentice] = 'True'Then 0
When [Apprentice] = 'False' Then 
CASE 

WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate]),01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1,12,31)  THEN 0
WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,12,31) THEN 8
WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,12,31) THEN 16
WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,12,31) THEN 24 
WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,12,31) THEN 32
WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+6,01,01) AND 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1000,12,31) THEN 40 

END 

+

CASE 
WHEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(StartDate), 12,31) >= GETDATE() THEN datediff(day, 
[StartDate],datefromparts(datepart(year,[StartDate]),(12), 
(31)))/(30.42)*13.33
ELSE [ALCategory]
END AS int 

)
```

Comment: Missing one END ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good use of Whitespace and Line breaks are a really important, I highly recommend using both to make your code readable (not just for others but yourself as well) and thus easier to debug. If you format your code, then the reason becomes much more obvious:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
ADD AwardedLeave AS CAST (CASE WHEN [Apprentice] = 'True'THEN 0
                                WHEN [Apprentice] = 'False' THEN CASE WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate]),01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1,12,31)  THEN 0
                                                                        WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,12,31) THEN 8
                                                                        WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,12,31) THEN 16
                                                                        WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,12,31) THEN 24 
                                                                        WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,12,31) THEN 32
                                                                        WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+6,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1000,12,31) THEN 40 
                                                                END +
                                                                CASE WHEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(StartDate), 12,31) >= GETDATE() THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [StartDate],DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,[StartDate]),(12), (31)))/(30.42)*13.33
                                                                        ELSE [ALCategory]
                                                                END AS int);
```

Notice, your first `CASE` expression has no `END`; hence the error at `AS` (the keyword `END` is expected):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
ADD AwardedLeave AS CAST (CASE WHEN [Apprentice] = 'True'THEN 0
                               WHEN [Apprentice] = 'False' THEN CASE WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate]),01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1,12,31)  THEN 0
                                                                     WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,12,31) THEN 8
                                                                     WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,12,31) THEN 16
                                                                     WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,12,31) THEN 24 
                                                                     WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,12,31) THEN 32
                                                                     WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+6,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1000,12,31) THEN 40 
                                                                END +
                                                                CASE WHEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(StartDate), 12,31) >= GETDATE() THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [StartDate],DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,[StartDate]),(12), (31)))/(30.42)*13.33
                                                                     ELSE [ALCategory]
                                                                END
                          END AS int);
```

Comment: Cheers!! The Whitespace and line breaks does make it way easier to spot. thanks for that tip

Answer (score 0):

Your code is alright, but you missed on END in case when, Please go through below code.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
ADD AwardedLeave as CAST 
(
CASE
When [Apprentice] = 'True'Then 0
When [Apprentice] = 'False' Then 
                                CASE 
                                WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate]),01,01) AND 
                                DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1,12,31)  THEN 0
                                WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,01,01) AND 
                                DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,12,31) THEN 8
                                WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,01,01) AND 
                                DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,12,31) THEN 16
                                WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,01,01) AND 
                                DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,12,31) THEN 24 
                                WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,01,01) AND 
                                DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,12,31) THEN 32
                                WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+6,01,01) AND 
                                DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1000,12,31) THEN 40 
                                END 
                                +
                                CASE 
                                WHEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(StartDate), 12,31) >= GETDATE() THEN datediff(day, 
                                [StartDate],datefromparts(datepart(year,[StartDate]),(12), 
                                (31)))/(30.42)*13.33
                                ELSE [ALCategory]
                                END 
END
AS int 
)
```